# Thymeleaf Spring 5 cannot find html template inside web-inf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to send email using thymeleaf for the email content, but it seems it cannot find the html template inside WEB-INF/templates/notifications.

I am using thymeleaf spring 5 on spring boot. `Spring boot (2.0.2.RELEASE)` and `Thymeleaf-spring5 (3.0.11.RELEASE)`

Below are my configuration/changes:

**POM**

```
...
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

**NotificationTemplateConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class NotificationTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "myTemplateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(myTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver myTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver myTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        myTemplateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/templates/notifications/");
        myTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        myTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        myTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        // I tried adding these lines but still it does not work
        // myTemplateResolver.setOrder(0);
        // myTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

        return myTemplateResolver;
    }
}
```

**EmailService**

```
@Component
public class EmailService {

   ...

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "myTemplateEngine")
    private SpringTemplateEngine m_myTemplateEngine;

   ...

    private String buildContent() {
        final Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("recvName", getRecvName());
        context.setVariable("inquiry", getInquiry());
        context.setVariable("logoImageUrl", getLogoImageUrl());

        // This is causing the error as it cannot find `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html`, but this file really exists
        return m_templateEngine.process("inquiry-notification", context);
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = m_javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, ConstantUtil.CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        String content = buildContent();
        helper.setFrom(getFromEmail());
        helper.setReplyTo(getNoReplyEmail());
        helper.setText(content, true);
        helper.setSubject(getSubject());
        helper.setTo(getRecipientEmail());

        m_javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
     
}
```

Now, I am getting an error on `buildContent()`:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

**Problem**

The file `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html` is existing and it is inside `WEB-INF/templates/notifications` even if I check the war file. The problem is on `m_templateEngine.process("inquiry-notification", context)` as it cannot find `inquiry-notification` even if it exists. If I comment out this and just return a hard coded string (for testing only)... it will send the email without any error.

This `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html` really exists, but I am out of idea on why it cannot find it.

Any idea on why it cannot find the file inside WEB-INF and how to fix it?

**Update:**
If I change the prefix into:
myTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/notifications/");

and move the folder from `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/` into `resources/templates/notifications`.

Everything works, but I want to use `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/` and not `resources/templates/notifications`.

As what @Ralph commented, it can be seen in the exception that it is reading from class path resource and not context resource.

My problem now is how can I make it read from context resource (WEB-INF/templates/notifications) and not from class path resource (resources/templates/notifications).

Comment: Could you try adding a `/` before "WEB-INF" in `myTemplateResolver.setPrefix`? e.g. `myTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/notifications/");`

Comment: The problem is, that Spring takes it as a class path resource (that is what the exception sayes) but zou configure the path for a context resource.

Comment: I already tried this `/WEB-INF/templates/notifications/` but still I have the same problem

Comment: Hi @Ralph what change or config do I need for it to see/find `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html`? Based from the codes I get from googling... do I have the wrong setting of template resolver's prefix and suffix? In the error logs, it is showing `WEB-INF/templates/notifications/inquiry-notification.html` which is my expected file path and it exists inside the war file also... but I am not sure on how to set it so that spring takes it as context resource.